# How to flip between themes in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, themes

So I'm thinking of building an app with a dark and a light theme

I have separated into 2 files dark.js and light.js

then im going to have a reducer that gets fired by coming through from a query param to trigger the case to change to light and dark

however, Im stuck at the next part. what would be the best way to then say use either the light/dark file/object?

I was thinking of setting all the css in the reducer but that seems like overkill

has anyone got any good ideas?

Comment: That's a classic use case for React context, see this tutorial: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context

Comment: is this the best way even though I'm using redux? I really need the app to load in the desired state. rather than button click. so it would either load in dark/light from the beginning.

Comment: Context and redux are not mutually exclusive, but you could just as well set a layout mode property in the redux state, e.g. with value "light" or "dark". All components that render something would have to receive this as a prop, selecting different styles depending on the mode. How exactly you implement this would also depend how you style your components, if you use plain CSS, Sass, or a CSS-in-JS lib like styled-componenrs or JSS.